# How can a remore long running process return results?

Tags: ssh, remote

I plan to have a long-running process (a Blender render, from 5 minutes to an hour) run on a remote Linux machine. What I am currently thinking of is a very simple process:

1. move file to remote machine
2. start render with ssh
3. get the render output file

This would be one or two bash scripts - nothing more complex.

In an ideal scenario, I would disconnect the ssh session from the remote machine, and only get the file once the render is done. It's ok to wait for as long as it's necessary to get the render.

Disconnecting seems the proper thing to do as I might launch renders on 20 machines at the same time - I don't know if it's a good idea to keep as many ssh sessions going.

What's the simplest way to handle that?

I am thinking of a couple alternatives:

- use ssh to periodically check if a blender process is running on the remote machine, and if the output file is available
- have curl on the remote machine upload the result of the rendering process to the machine originating the request

The thing here is:

- the originating machine might be behind a NAT
- the rendering machine might be provisioned on the fly to deal with peak demand

Is there something better out there that I - in my ignorance of such things - do not know of?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details and background information. How long is "long-running" in your use case? Why do you want to disconnect from the remote machine? Are there any time requirements for getting the result file of a finished process?

Comment: done! 5-60 mins; seems like the right thing to do; no issue with waiting

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle multiple connections. I don't think that it would be a problem to have 20 open ssh connections. You might have to handle lost connections, though. With the expected process run time it might be sufficient to close the connection and to poll every machine once per minute. Instead of checking for a running process you could also use a wrapper script on the remote machine that renames the output file when finished or creates an additional file to be used as a condition for finished processing.

Comment: You could still send an email once a job is finished.

Comment: Similar question at https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47386/66778. Also consider https://arachnoid.com/python/blender_network_render/index.html, http://nil.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2018/projects/frender.pdf, etc. Basically: https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=blender%20distributed%20rendering%20server

Comment: neat! I'll read through